# MYSQL set the current record date to previous record date based on search filter

Tags: mysql

I would like track previous record date and I am looking for a way to either create a view or to create a new previous date column.

sample table:

```
select id, previous, current 
from reports
where prod_id = 25 
order by id desc;

+------+---------------+---------------+
| id   |      previous |      current  |
+------+---------------+---------------+
|  229 |    0000-00-00 |    2018-03-19 |
|  208 |    0000-00-00 |    2018-01-05 |
|  134 |    0000-00-00 |    2017-08-22 |
+------+---------------+---------------+
```

After reading other topics I have tried the following:

```
select id, current, @previous:= current as previous
from reports join (select @previous := 0) dummy
where prod_id = 25 
order by id desc;

+------+---------------+---------------+
| id   |      current  |      previous |
+------+---------------+---------------+
|  229 |    2018-03-19 |    2018-03-19 |
|  208 |    2018-01-05 |    2018-01-05 |
|  134 |    2017-08-22 |    2017-08-22 |
+------+---------------+---------------+
```

In the 2nd example the previous and the current are still the same. Although i would like for the table to be like this:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+
| id   |      previous |      current  |
+------+---------------+---------------+
|  229 |    2018-01-05 |    2018-03-19 |
|  208 |    2017-08-22 |    2018-01-05 |
|  134 |    2017-06-14 |    2017-08-22 |
+------+---------------+---------------+
```

I am trying to figure out what I am missing in my sample sql that doesnt pick up previous record current date. And then change it to update.

Comment: What MySQL version do you have `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland 5.5.52-MariaDB

Comment: Can you also add better example data and not some resultset of a query?

Comment: @RaymondNijland i have created sql fiddle with the sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de59c/2